# UI-Router does not correctly route to child view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have a state:

[image]

I want to move to this state from a button on the header.  This button is located in my index.html file:

[image]

The highlighted line makes a call to the Gallery() function which does some logic but eventually calles $state.go on the 'submitMoment' state.

[image]

Now, I want to add this abstract state to my 'submitMoment' state:

[image]

I did it like so:

[image]

Now, I want to call it using the same function as before.  I would have thought that something like this would just work:

[image]

But it does not.  I have also tried adding a view to my 'submitMoment' state but that does nothing either.  It basically only works if the state is NOT a child view.  I get the feeling this has something to do with me calling $state.go in index.html in which router.js does not know about since it is technically not really a route.  If this is the case would I need to make two child views?

I am not too familiar with UI-Route.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have ng-view tag within layout/tabsController.html? If it is not there it doesn't work, becuase ui-router replaces ui-view in index.html with tabsController and looks for another ui-view to replace with child state

Comment: I got this to work, thanks.